# How to toggle krunner with a modifier only shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, kde-plasma-5, kwin

I would like to toggle the `krunner` launcher with a modifier only shortcut. Modifier only shortcuts can be bound to D-Bus method calls in `kwinrc` (for example, see this [blog post](https://bucharjan.cz/blog/plasma-custom-modifier-only-shortcuts.html)). I would like one key that both opens and closes `krunner` similar to how the meta key both opens and closes the launchers in GNOME and Plasma (the other, default launcher that is not `krunner`).

The method `org.kde.krunner,/App,,display` can be used to open `krunner`. However, I have not found a related method for closing it. In my testing, I found that simply `kill`ing the `krunner` process closed the `krunner` display without other adverse effects. I created a small D-Bus service in Python to kill `krunner` and was able to bind it to a modifier key successfully. However, when you open `krunner`, it leaves the `krunner` process running (I guess to make it faster to open the next time), so one can not simply set a keybinding to run `krunner` if it is not running and kill it if it is running.

Is there any way to query the state of `krunner` so it can be killed if it is currently displayed and display it otherwise? If so, I could change my D-Bus service to do this. Or perhaps there is a completely different approach that could achieve the main goal of a toggling `krunner` with a modifier only shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `org.kde.krunner,/App,,display`, use `org.kde.kglobalaccel,/component/krunner,,invokeShortcut,run command`.
See more [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KRunner).

---

Edit: After I updated to Plasma 5.17.5, the method above doesn't work anymore. I have to revert to `org.kde.krunner,/App,,display` and then use Esc to close krunner.

---

Edit 2: solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/dleoqa/how_to_run_bash_script_with_meta_key/). Use xdotool to simulate Esc key.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use `org.kde.krunner,/App,,toggleDisplay`.